Persimmon black splotches vs black spots. Safe to eat?
Never had nor heard of persimmons until they were recently introduced in my grocery store, and I have a couple of questions on what's safe to eat.
I've noticed that they can have black spots around 1cm or 2 in diameter with sometimes?/always? a break in the skin. I don't know if the black comes because of the rupture, or if the black comes with a shrinking of the skin that causes it to eventually rupture, i.e. I don't know the order of cause-and-effect here. I first thought they're the former, but in one batch I saw so many that it might be the latter. I've been rejecting them on the idea that they all had their skin broken, but maybe they're more like banana spots?, and they just indicate they're about to spoil?
Then in the latest batch, there were a lot of persimmons that instead of those black spots had black splotches. The skin on them is perfect. They look perfect, ignoring the color. The flesh on the other side of that black skin was also perfect, last time I cut one open.
Searched online, but information is kind of scarce and inconsistent. Some sites say black spots are from a fungal infection, others from a bacterial infection, others say it's a sunspot, others say it's an accumulation of sugars. Most sites don't talk about whether it's safe to eat, maybe because they seem to be gardening sites rather than food sites. The ones that do though always say that they are safe to eat, regardless if it's from a fungal infection. They never have pictures of the persimmon or they have a picture of a leaf of the persimmon tree. They also aren't consistent in that they interchange the terms "spot" for "stain" or others, so I'm not sure what type of "spot"/"stain"/"splotch" they're talking about or if they even imply a break in the skin.
BTW, the ones with the spots seem to be Fuyu (by my estimate, the store didn't specify), and the ones with the splotches seem to be Hachiya (ditto).
Instinct tells me a break in the skin is what matters, so the Fuyu one is bad and the Hachiyas are fine. I kind of feel like the small broken spots on the Hachiya are too small to matter, but that's based on feeling rather than logic.
What do you all think?
Pictures:


Closeup of that third Hachiya, showing more spots:


The first photo shows an infection. I can't tell the cause from the image, but it is certainly rotting. For fungal causes it is fine to remove the fungus contaminated area with a wide margin and eat the rest, but bacterial rots may not. Fungal ones will put up (short or long) fuzzy hairs and either be white or blue/green; whereas bacterial will go softer, start to ooze juice and typically, but not always, smell bad.
The second photo shows a discolouration that could be the result of a bruise or possibly sunburn of the fruit. I've not seen persimmon looking quite like this before, they normally show a blush in the region that is more exposed.
The third (and on the fruit on the right in the second photo) shows some dry cuts in the surface. These are fine to cut out for cosmetic purposes only and eat the remainder. You can eat the brown bits too, they will just be tougher than the rest and may not taste as nice. The brown in this case is caused by exposure to the air and oxidation by a polyphenol oxidase enzyme that is naturally present in the fruit.

The discolouration being a bruise seems very unlikely. It's not softer, nor dented. They were also all very consistent in their stain being on the side like that. About cutting out the fungus, I thought cutting out fungus is only doable on hard foods like a block of parmesan cheese.

BTW, sorry I can't upvote you because of my lack of reputation. I'm also waiting before accepting to give chance to others.

@Migas See https://www.fsis.usda.gov/food-safety/safe-food-handling-and-preparation/food-safety-basics/molds-food-are-they-dangerous Scroll down to the table near the bottom. If your persimmons are soft then you should indeed discard the whole fruit. If they are still quite firm, then you can cut it out. Having said that, based on the colour of your fruits, they are near ripe and starting to get soft/mushy (my favoured state for them). The modern varieties are edible in almost any state apart from green, but the old varieties needed to be mushy before being edible or were astringent.

The first one is rot. The telltale sign is the depression and the mushiness relative to the rest of the fruit (important to note that this is relative, because the ripest – and most delicious – persimmons will themselves become quite soft). If you look closely you can see that the skin around that spot is wrinkly, which is a sign that it is starting to be consumed by whatever is causing the rot.
The large stains in the second photo seem to be normal. The entire batch of persimmons at the grocery store on my last visit 3 days ago looked exactly like this. I ate a couple and the stain was superficial and had no impact on the taste or mouth feel. The shared timing of your post and my own experience suggests this is a specific persimmon varietal for which this appearance is normal. Fuyu and Hachiya persimmons are the most common varietal, but there are many others.
I have no specific knowledge to  say what the  damage is on the last persimmon, but based on personal experience with persimmons and other hard fruit @bob1's answer that these are harmless dry cuts makes sense.
